# I want to create an animation of tape distortion

Tags: animation, modifiers

I would like to create an animation of the subtle distortion of the tape as it is turned over. (Please reffer attached image).
[image]

There are several points I find very difficult in this animation.

・The tape is flat before the tape is turned over.

・The tape is distorted only in the very area where it is being folded.

・The tape after the tape is turned over is flat again.
I would like to express the above.

Currently, I have created an animation that simply flips the tape.
However, I do not know how to create the distortion expression.

I have created an animation of flipping the tape by applying a curve modifier to the tape and moving the curve.
I have attached a blend file, so I hope you can take a look at it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give your tape object a *Lattice* modifier and create a lattice that you'll deform the way you want (here my lattice has a *Resolution* of (*U/V/W*) 3/12/1 :

[image]

For the small curvy fold, add some vertices to your curve so that the tape follows the same shape:

[image]

Comment: oh!! You are genius!! Thank you so much for polite answer!!
I will try it ! Thank you again! 